# Php file preview button is not showing in Internet Explorer browser

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Code is below. There is a file preview button which is showing in chrome and firefox well but in IE it's not showing.

```
$ua = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $ua) || (strpos($ua, Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)) {
// do stuff for IE
}
else{

if(strtolower($aRow["extension"])=='pdf')
{ 
$editable .="<a class=\"iframe\" href=\"javascript:viewPdf('http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$script_dir}{
$aRow["path"]}');\" title=\"Preview\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in\"></span></a>&nbsp;";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `if` condition is preventing Internet Explorer from rendering the button. In order to show it on any browser, you should move the second if condition outside the original `if-else` block, for example:

```
$ua = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $ua) || (strpos($ua, 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)) {
    // do stuff for IE
}
else {
    // do stuff for other browsers that are not IE
}

if(strtolower($aRow["extension"])=='pdf') { 
    // render the button regardless browser User Agent (UA)
    $editable .="<a class=\"iframe\" href=\"javascript:viewPdf('http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$script_dir}{
    $aRow["path"]}');\" title=\"Preview\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in\"></span></a>&nbsp;";
}
```